# Array.includes not working as string.includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want something like string.includes it can detect character among string but array.includes("a") can only detect if array[0] = "a" and return false when array[0] = "ab"

Is there anyway i can achieve string.includes in array without function and loop (1 line code) ? Thanks

```
var array = ["a", "b"];
array.includes("a"); //return true
var array = ["ab","b"];
array.includes("a"); //return false
Var string = "ab";
string.includes("a"); //return true
```

I want string.includes working with array without function and loop

Comment: do you have some examples?

Comment: Let me edit example

Comment: Are you only going to look for single characters, or would you also do `array.includes("ab")`?

Comment: @trincot ab is good too thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `join` variant below will cause problems if the string match itself contains a comma.

```js
const array = ['ab', 'cd']

console.log(array.some(i=>i.includes('a')))

// or

console.log(array.join().includes('a'))
```

Comment: is there any way i can make it only detect string in a specified range for example from array[0] to array[11] ?

Comment: @Error2.0 yes, just do `array.slice(0,12)` first. It sounds like you have not discovered the documentation for Array yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to `Array` prototype and use it as `includes`

```js
if (Array.prototype.includesString === undefined) {
  /*
   * Checks if a string[] contains a item which includes the str
   * @param {string} str - sub-string to check within each item
   * @returns {boolean} whether an item in the string[] contains the str
   */
  Array.prototype.includesString = function (str) {
    return this.some(item => item.includes(str));
  };
}

const result = ['ab', 'cd'].includesString('a');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

For handle this, you can stringify it for each of them or all of them, by using "JSON.stringify()" method. It's not the original use case of that but it's so useful especially handling searching actions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).